# Possible race condition when scripting headphone plug-in event

Tags: scripting, audio, acpi, jack, acpid

I'm currently trying to script the headphone plug-in/out event. I found out that I can script this quite easily as an `acpi` event..

I created a file in `/etc/acpi/events/` with the event `event=jack[ /]headphone`, which then just calls my script.

I've also determined the file and exact line, which holds information about whether the headphones are currently plugged in or not. In the file `/proc/asound/card0/codec#0` one specific `Pin-ctls:` is `0x00` if plugged in and `0x40: OUT` if unplugged.

Now the problem I see there, is when I check the the current status of the headphone jack, as soon as the acpi event is triggered, will the `codec#0` file already contain the current value? Might I have a race condition here? Or is it safe to use like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem can be easily circumvented, by checking for the specific `plug`/`unplug` event on the jack. The solution below will give the script the information about the specific jack events, which will mute sound, when the jack is unplugged.

`/etc/acpi/events/jack`:

```
event=jack[ /]headphone
action=/etc/acpi/actions/jack.sh "%e"
```

`/etc/acpi/actions/jack.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

event=$(echo "$1" | cut -d " " -f 3)

case "$event" in
    plug)
        ;;
    unplug)
    amixer set Master mute
        ;;
    *)  
        #null
esac
```